# Swift3, Array (UnsafeBufferPointer...) Если большой буфер, то падает приложение

Tags: xcode, swift3

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу решить потому что тупой)

Вот код:

```
let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
try! file.read(into: buf)

let array = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.floatChannelData?[0] , count:Int(buf.frameLength)))
```

Если аудио-файл больше 12 минут, то падает приложение при попытке записи в **array**, предварительно указывая на **DidReceiveMemoryWarning**. 
Кто-нибудь знает как с этим бороться?

В моем случае получается 26459069 точек, которые он пытается закинуть в массив и не получается. Мне не нужны они все, только каждая трехсотая от предыдущей, а как это организовать? Если выдернуть каждую трехсотую, то получится около 86000 точек и все было бы норм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем случае можно сделать несколько оптимизаций и выбрать необходимый баланс.

Исходные данные

Все проверки на аудиокниге размером 200 Мб. Все переменные - поля класса. Замеры в симуляторе, так что не объективно, но повторяемо.

0 Код из Вашего примера:

```
file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
try! file.read(into: buf)
array = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.floatChannelData?[0] , count:Int(buf.frameLength)))
```

Время выполнения 30,7 секунд, потребление памяти 3.5 Гб:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 Вам необходимы только каждый 300-й элемент, поэтому можем пройтись циклом и добавить в массив только необходимые элементы. Код:

```
file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url!)
format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
try! file.read(into: buffer!)
for i in stride(from: 0, to: Int(buffer!.frameLength), by: 300) {
    arr.append((buffer?.floatChannelData?[0].advanced(by: i).pointee)!)
}
print(arr.count)
```

Время выполнения 21.1 секунды, потребление памяти значительно ниже, 2.4 Гб:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 Мы можем снизить потребление памяти, если будем читать из файла только то что нам необходимо:

```
file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url!)
format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: 1)
for i in stride(from: 0, to: file.length, by: 300) {
    file.framePosition = i
    try! file.read(into: buffer, frameCount: 1)
    arr.append((buffer?.floatChannelData?[0].pointee)!)
}
print(arr.count)
```

Время выполнения значительно дольше, 898.1 секунд, т.к много дисковых операций. Потребление памяти низкое, 49 Мб:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 Комбинируем 1 и 2:

```
file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url!)
format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
let readingMultiplier = 1000
let bufferSize = 300 * readingMultiplier
buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize))
for i in stride(from: 0, to: file.length, by: bufferSize) {
    file.framePosition = i
    try! file.read(into: buffer, frameCount: AVAudioFrameCount(bufferSize))
    for j in stride(from: 0, to: Int(buffer!.frameLength), by: 300) {
        arr.append((buffer?.floatChannelData?[0].advanced(by: j).pointee)!)
    }
}
print(arr.count)
```

Время выполнения 19,6 секунд, меняется от размера буфера. Потребление памяти для данного примера 52 Мб, меняется от размера буфера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, все верно, сделал примерно так же. Только одно замечание: for j in stride(from: 0, through: Int(buffer!.frameLength) - 1, by: 300). Добавил - 1 иначе он будет добавлять 2 одинаковых значения - с конца буфера и с начала следующего.